# Extracting all data from data grid on command event using wpf

Tags: wpf

I have a datagrid in wpf to where users will enter data into two of the cells and then the save button is clicked to where is runs a binding command.  My issue is how do I retrieve the updated data in the cells on the command.

```
    <Grid>
        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="45" Margin="10,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="360">
            <Label Content="These names were not found." Width="200" Height="25" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" Foreground="Blue" Canvas.Left="80" />
            <Label Content="Please save the Missing Names before continuing." Width="350" Height="33" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" Foreground="Blue" Canvas.Top="20" IsEnabled="False" />
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Margin="10, 70, 0, 0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220">
            <Label Content="{Binding RowCount}" IsEnabled="False" Width="220" Height="25" />
        </Canvas>
        <!--<DataGrid x:Name="dgNames" Width="320" Height="244" Margin="0, 20 0, 0" ItemsSource="{Binding MissingNamesList}"></DataGrid>-->
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgNames" Width="340" Height="244" Margin="0, 20 0, 0" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MissingNamesList, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                  CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="EmpNum" Header="Employee Number" Binding="{Binding Path=EmployeeNum}" Width="70" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource WrappedColumnHeaderStyle}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Passport" Header="Passport" Binding="{Binding Path=Passport}" Width="55" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="FirstName" Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding Path=First_Name}" Width="90" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LastName" Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Last_Name}" Width="100" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="50" Margin="0, 0, 0, 20">
            <Button x:Name="btnRestart" Content="Restart Process" Width="130" Height="45" Margin="0, 0, 40, 0" Command="{Binding Path=RestartCommand}" />
            <Button x:Name="btnSave" Content="Save Names" Width="130" Height="45" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>


    public void Save()
    {
        string strQuery = string.Empty;


        foreach (var inp in clsCommon.grpMsgNmsList)
        {
            strQuery = "Insert Into [tblCV_lkpEEFullnames] ([EmployeeNumber], [PassportCode], [LastName], [FirstName]) ";
            strQuery += " Values ('" + inp.EmployeeNum + "', '" + inp.Passport + "', '" + inp.First_Name + "', '" + inp.Last_Name + "')";

            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(com.StrPrdConString))
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, sqlCon))
                {
                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                sqlCon.Close();

            }
        }
        //DataGridColumn dgCol = dgNames.Columns[0];

    }
```

Comment: You simply have to access the MissingNamesList (the data source of the DataGrid). Editing a cell, edits the associated property on the data item.